# Input fields to text output

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, text, input

What im trying to do is create a webform that will take the information put into the fields to add to a predefined text. the code I have so far is as follows:

```
<form action="" method="post">
<input type="reset" value="Clear">
<p>
<input type="text" name="casenumber" value="Case Number" onclick="this.select()" size="25"/>
</p>
<p>
<input type="text" name="name" value="Name" onclick="this.select()" size="25" />
</p>
<p>
<input type="text" name="dealer code" value="Dealer Code" onclick="this.select()" size="25" />
</p>
<p>
<input type="text" name="cid" value="CID" onclick="this.select()" size="25" />
</p>
<p>
<input type="text" name="callback" value="Callback#" onclick="this.select()" size="25" />
</p>
<p>
<input type="text" name="authentication" value="Dealer Authentication" onclick="this.select()" size="25" />
</p>
<p>
<input type="text" name="email" value="Email" onclick="this.select()" size="25" />
</p>
<p>
<input type="text" name="ptn" value="PTN" onclick="this.select()" size="25" />
</p>
<p>
<input type="text" name="ban" value="BAN" onclick="this.select()" size="25" />
</p>
<p>
<input type="text" name="banauth" value="Ban Authentication" onclick="this.select()" size="25" />
</p>
<p>
<input type="text" name="type" value="Type of Request" onclick="this.select()" size="25" />
</p>
<p>
Actions Taken:<br/>
<textarea name="actions" rows="5" cols="50"></textarea>
</p>
<p>
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</p>
```

Now I want all of the information entered into these fields to be added to this

SFDC - TSO Case number: *input inserted here*

Dealer Name: *input inserted here*

Dealer code: *input inserted here*

CID: *input inserted here*

Callback#: *input inserted here*

Dealer Authentication: *input inserted here*

Email:  *input inserted here*

PTN#: *input inserted here*

BAN: *input inserted here*

BAN Authentication: *input inserted here*

Type of Request: *input inserted here*

Actions Taken: *input inserted here*

Have not been able to find how to do this so any help is appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by "add to a predefined text."? What exactly is this "predefined text"? Is it a text file? A string? An object? Other HTML?

Comment: I want the output to be the bottom form inserting all the text entered in the text fields where it says "input inserted here" that way I can just copy and paste it all as text

Comment: so basically once the submit button is pressed it will generate all that text with the answers so that I can copy and paste it

Comment: This must need [tag:javascript]

Comment: Okay that is a bit more clear. I am assuming you are doing this with JavaScript. What have you tried? Also you should update your tags.

Comment: I am extremely new to this I haven't tried anything, all I have done is that basic html I provided.

Comment: So are you looking to have this go into the textarea? Is that where you would want to copy it from?

Comment: I would like to add a new text area at the bottom where it inserts all the text into that I can copy. generally I fill all this information out in notepad but that gets quite tedious and figured it would be a lot easier to just fill out a webform and then have it generate my notes that I can copy and paste...the text area I have now is where I would put any additional notes so I would need another text area

Comment: @MitchBuckley I see you're fairly new to StackOverflow. Please next time try to provide at least your best try and explain where exactly it went wrong (you cannot expect one to write code for you without showing some effort from your side).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript) function which is using the placeholder attribute to generate the titles of values for the text generated:

```
/**
* fId: the form id
* dId: the div id which want to add the text to it
**/
    function printToDiv(fId, dId){
          f = document.getElementById(fId);
          i = f.getElementsByTagName('input');
          iTxt = Array();
          k = 0;
          out = '';
          for (j = 0; j < i.length; j++){
            if (i[j].type == 'text'){
              iTxt[k] = i[j];
              k++;
            }
          }
          for (n =0; n < iTxt.length; n++){
            out += "<b>"+iTxt[n].placeholder+":</b> "+iTxt[n].value+"<br />\n";
          }
          div = document.getElementById(dId);
          div.innerHTML = out;
        }
```

A generalized DEMO could be found [**here**](http://jsbin.com/wugicusawi/1/) or [**here**](http://jsbin.com/givuxefita/1/). Ofcourse you can apply any validation for the data by calling any other function inside the regarded function and you can call it by any way you want, for example, from onsubmit event.

Comment: now that demo is also exactly what im looking for, i don't know how to code that for the exact fields i am looking for above

Comment: As I regarded in the answer, the same way, supply the function call with the form id, add id attribute to your form, then create a div with specified id attribute and supply it to the function too. Also, you have specify placeholder attribute for your input fields or title attribute. However, title attribute will need little modification to the function.

Comment: THAT is absolutely perfect the only thing is the text area for actions taken, is there anyway for that to also copy down when you hit print?

Comment: been trying to figure this out but cant seem to figure out how to add the text area to the print function as well

Comment: i apologize, what i meant was i wanted the information in the text area to also print to the bottom just like the rest of the information does

Comment: It is very simple, but I suggest to read [**this tutorial**](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_document.asp) about DOM.

Comment: i tried doing it on my own from your 2nd demo you sent however i could not figure out how to make the textarea text also print down with the rest

Comment: @sємsєм any reason for not using `var`? Also `iTxt = Array();` why not `var iTxt = [];` or even with a more descriptive name?

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan for descriptive variables names, it is because coding quick answer, for specific task.

Comment: Never mind the variable names, I like also CodeGolfing :) My biggest concern is polluting the `window` namespace.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you have to use a placeholder.
Look:

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_placeholder.asp
Exercise:

```html
<form action="" method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="X" placeholder="Some text..." />
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't care about language this could be easily done with JavaScript. Just add the class to all your inputs and add a span next to your defined text

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <input id='txtCaseNumber' class="copyValue" placeholder="case number"/>
    <input id='txtDealer' class="copyValue" placeholder="Dealer Name"/>
    Case Number: <span data-inputId="txtCaseNumber"></span>
    Dealer Name: <span data-inputId="txtDealer"></span>

    <script>    
       $(document).ready(function(){
          $(".copyValue").blur(function(){              
            var inputId = $(this).attr('id');               
            var ident = "span[data-inputId='" + inputId + "']";             
            $(ident).html($(this).val());           
        });
      });
   </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: i see what you mean but i don't really understand how this works, i tried copying your code but it doesn't output it so not really sure how to do this

Comment: The output isn't the prettiest in my example I can update it if it would help.  But after you exit each textbox the value of whatever is in the textbox should be copied to the span.  So there is no button to press, it should happen automatically

Comment: im also trying to do this out of a local HTML file just opened on my computer so i don't know if that matters or not, but when text is entered into the box it is not being copied to the span

Comment: Are you mousing out of the textbox?  if you just type in there it won't copy you have to mouse out (or tab or whatever).  I made a fiddle so you can check it out with the format a little better for you.
https://jsfiddle.net/RVAProgrammer/wktz4g4o/

Comment: @RVAProgrammer the question was tagged [tag:javascript] so try always to provide a JS version or at least note that your example uses jQuery

Comment: Also `$(this).attr('id')` and `$(this).val()` can easily be used as `this.id` and `this.val`. Know your JS properties!

Answer (score 0):

If I am understanding your question correctly. You could do something like this. But this is not the only way, it is just a way.

**Sample HTML:**

```
<div class="container">
   <input type="text" value="something"/>
   <input type="text" value="something"/>
   <input type="submit" value="submit" id="submit"/>
</div>
<div id="output"></div>
```

**JS:**

```
var a = [
    "SFDC - TSO Case number:",
    "Dealer Name:", 
    "Dealer code:", 
    "CID:", 
    "Callback#:", 
    "Dealer Authentication:", 
    "Email:", 
    "PTN#:",
    "BAN:",
    "BAN Authentication:", 
    "Type of Request:", 
    "Actions Taken:"
];

var values = [];

$("#submit").on('click', function()
{
    var form = $('.container');
    var inputs = form.find('input').not('.exclude'); // add this class to the inputs you don't want to collect the values of, IE clear and submit
    var l = inputs.length;
    var html = '';

    for(var i = 0; i < l; i++)
    {
       var value = inputs.eq(i).val();
       values.push(value);
    }

    for(var i = 0, ln = a.length; i < ln; i++)
    {
        html += '<p>' + a[i] + ' ' + values[i] + '</p>';
    }

    $('#output').append(html); 
});
```

*Note: I used [jQuery](https://jquery.com/) for this example and cleaned up / changed the HTML a bit.*

**Demo:**

http://jsfiddle.net/prb75qvt/4/

Comment: ok when i look at your demo that is exactly what im looking for however when i click submit it doesn't actually generate any text

Comment: What do you mean by generate text? Are you looking to add text to the values from the inputs? Also I have update and noticed.. I had an error. So might want to re-check.

Comment: Also I have updated my demo and code to use a for loop instead of decrementing while loop. As it makes more sense for this. Typically the while is faster.. force of habit I guess.

Comment: when you click the submit button shouldn't it generate the text into the output field?

Comment: It generates the values of the inputs into the output. Okay, I see what you mean.

Comment: Okay, I have updated my answer.. hopefully this is more along the lines of what you are trying to do.

Comment: thank you so much, how would i put the code into say notepad and save as an html file to use ?

Comment: @MitchBuckley, just give it a .html extension and proper HTML tags. You will have to do some reading / tutorials on how to write HTML. I suggest starting here http://www.codecademy.com/courses/html-one-o-one/0/1

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you want to take an text fron an input box and paste it somewhere else. Use this code template :

HTML CODE
(The onchange is optional, I just like to use it because it activates a function when the text changes)

```
<input id="newText" type="text" onchange="myFunction()">
<p>Your text</p><p id="oldText"></p>
```

JS CODE
("oldText" is used as a placeholder)

```
function myFunction() {
var inputText = document.getElementById("newText").value;
document.getElementById("oldText").innerHTML = inputText
}
```

Comment: `<input>` is a [void](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/syntax.html#void-elements) element and **cannot** have the closing `</input>`.

Comment: Also, using your example, the JS, by selecting over and over again elements using `document.getElementByID("blabla")` would become extremely hard to operate with. Use classes and loops.

Comment: Thank you for fixing my code, @Roko C. Buljan :). What concerns classes and loops, I could have done that, but I just wanted to get the bases of the code for more clarity.